# Swift: Image does not appear in the ImageView when added to a new view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

For an app I am working on, the profile page has a horizontal scroll across the top, in which there are 3 views, each spanning the width of the device. On one view is the profile picture, on the other are details and the other are social links.

The problem I am getting is when I create a `UIImageView` called `profileImage`, and then assign the users profile image to this view, it all worked fine before I added this scroll view.

Then I created this scroll view, and `profileImage` sits in `firstView`, the first view of the scroll. However the image never appears, this is not just a problem with the image as I have also attempted adding default images in the assests.

```
var profileImage: UIImageView!
```

below is the code block for creating the `firstView` of the slide and adding the image to the image view.

```
        let firstView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height))
    firstView.backgroundColor = Colours.blue
    scrollView.addSubview(firstView)
    var img = UIImage(named: "default_image")
    profileImage = UIImageView(image: img!)
    profileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    if let imageUrl = user.profilePictureUrl {
        profileImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(imageUrl)
        println("THIS IS IMAGE URL: \(imageUrl)")
    }
    profileImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake((firstView.bounds.size.width - profileImage.frame.size.width) / 2.0, 10, 80, 80))
    firstView.addSubview(profileImage)
    firstView.bringSubviewToFront(profileImage)
```

The `imageUrl` appears, I know I am missing something really easy. Also I want to note that the `UIImageView` and the `UIScrollView` are not `IBOutlet`'s but created programmatically.

Comment: You create `profileImage` twice. The first instance won't be used at all. Is this your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have instantiated UIImageView object twice with same name "profileImage"; so your first profileImage is being overrided by the next profileImage. Comment in the last third line and set the frame like:

```
profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(x,x,x,x)
```

Comment: My God you diamond! thank you very much. I knew it would be something I simply overlooked